# how to add a column to identify specific combination of values in R?

Tags: r, string

I have a database with several columns ( >20) and 2 of these columns have the subject names. I would like to add another column with inside a number that identifies the combination of the two subjects.

Here is an example with only the 2 columns of names (I don't include the others for convenience):

```
ID1  ID2
A    B
A    C
A    B
B    C
A    B
B    A
C    B
```

And here is what i would like to create:

```
ID1  ID2 CODE
A    B   1
A    C   2
A    B   1
B    C   3
A    B   1
B    A   1
C    B   3
```

I am kind of new in R and I think it can be done with `stringr` but I am not sure how

Thanks for the help!

Simo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$CODE <- as.integer(
  factor(
    apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ""))
  )
)
#   ID1 ID2 CODE
# 1   A   B    1
# 2   A   C    2
# 3   A   B    1
# 4   B   C    3
# 5   A   B    1
# 6   B   A    1
# 7   C   B    3
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C"), 
  ID2 = c("B", "C", "B", "C", "B", "A", "B")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Var = paste0(sort(c(ID1, ID2)), collapse = '')) %>%
  group_by(Var) %>%
  mutate(CODE=cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Var)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  ID1   ID2    CODE
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 A     B         1
2 A     C         2
3 A     B         1
4 B     C         3
5 A     B         1
6 B     A         1
7 C     B         3
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C"), ID2 = c("B", 
"C", "B", "C", "B", "A", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work...it produces an error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Var`.
x 'x' must be atomic
i Input `Var` is `paste0(sort(c(ID1, ID2)), collapse = "")`.
i The error occurred in row 1.

Comment: It must be an error due to data, can you check if the structure is the same as that provided in your sample of data? Check if variables are character and not factors!

Comment: ah so this solution works only with factors? all the columns have to be factors?

Comment: No, please check that columns are of type character!

Comment: the variables ID1 and ID2 are character, the others are numbers and factors

Comment: @Simone I would need to see the data as we can use select to do the task. Could you invite me to chat?